# I want to understand BubbleSort but I am struggling to understand a specific part in the code my professor provided

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, bubble-sort

The only part I don't fully understand is the inner for loop conditions. In the outer for loop we declared that lastPos is array.length-1 , so if we were to pass an array of size 10, lasPos would equal 9 right? Okay, so now in the inner for loop, we say that as long as index <= lastPos-1 then we run whatever is inside but if we do index <= lastPos-1 would that not be 8 now? why wouldn't we just do lastPos instead of lastPos-1 in the inner loop?

```
//The IntBubbleSorter class provides a public static
//method for performing a bubble sort on an int array
public class IntBubbleSort 
{

    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int lastPosition;
        int[] myArray = new int[10];
        
        lastPosition = myArray.length-1;
        
        System.out.println(lastPosition);
        
    }
    
    //The bubbleSort method uses the bubble sort algorithm
    //to sort an int array
    
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
    {
        int lastPos;        //Position of the last element to compare
        int i;              //index of an element to compare
        int temp;           //used to swap to elements
        
        //The outer loop positions lastPos at the last element
        //to compare during each pass through the array. Initially
        //lastPos is the index of the last element in the array.
        //During each iteration, it is decreased by one.
        
        for(lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >=0 ; lastPos--)
        {
            //The inner loop steps through the array, comparing
            //each element with its neighbor. All of the elements
            //from index 0 through lastPos are involved in the 
            //comparison. If two elements are out of order, they
            //are swapped
            
            for(i = 0; i <= lastPos -1; i++)         //what the hell? 
            {
                //compare an element with its neighbor
                if(array[i] > array[i -1])
                {
                    //swap the two elements
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i +1] = temp;
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Manually write down the algorithm on paper with arrays of 3 or 4 elements. If you find a problem with the approach, or room for improvement, then you can take it to your professor and talk about it. It's also possible the code provided is just wrong

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= lastPos -1; i++)` may be rewritten as `for(i = 0; i < lastPos; i++)` which is a ubiquitous meme in c-like languages which use zero-based array indexing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a bug in the code. This line:

```
if(array[i] > array[i -1])
```

should be:

```
if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
```

This also shows why you want to loop until `lastPos-1`: this is because you will access an array element that is one index *further*. Or to state that in a different way: the right most pair within the subarray between index 0 and index `lastPos` (included), starts at `lastPos-1`.

In your example we would indeed run until index 8. This is because the final pair of values to compare are at index 8 and 9. If we would have gone to 9, then we would compare the value at 9 with that at index 10, but index 10 would be an out of range index.